# Why can we distribute the complex modulus? (looking for intuition/proof)

Tags: complex-numbers

if you have,

$$ z= z_1 \cdot z_2 ... z_n$$

then,

$$ |z| = |z_1 \cdot z_2 ... z_n| = |z_1| |z_2| |z_3| ... |z_n|$$

Now, why is this equality true?
$$|z_1 \cdot z_2 ... z_n| = |z_1| |z_2| |z_3| ... |z_n|$$

Comment: $r_1e^{i\theta_1}r_2e^{i\theta_2}=r_1r_2e^{i\theta}$ and induction on $n$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think about the polar form of a complex number.

If each $\displaystyle z_j=r_je^{i\theta_j}$, where $r_j=|z_j|$ (the modulus), and $\theta_j$ is the argument.

Then $z=z_1z_2z_3....z_n=(r_1r_2r_3...r_n)e^{i(\theta_1+\theta_2+\theta_3...\theta_n)}$

Answer (score 1):

$$ z_1 = r_1e^{i\theta}$$
$$z_2 = r_2 e^{i\phi}$$
$$ z_1 * z_2 = r_1 * r_2 e^{i \theta + i \phi}$$
$$ |z_1 z_2| = r_1 r_2$$
$$|z_1| = r_1$$
$$ |z_2| = r_2$$
$$ |z_1| * |z_2| = r_1 * r_2$$

Now, let P(n) contain the statement that $ |z_1| * |z_2| ... |z_n| = | z_1 z_2 z_3..z_n|$

$$P(1) = |z_1| = |z_1|$$

$$P(k) = |z_1| |z_2| |z_3|.......|z_k| = |z_1 z_2 z_3...z_k|$$

$$ P(k+1) =  |z_1| |z_2| |z_3|.......|z_k||z_{k+1}| = |z_1 z_2 z_3...z_k| |z_{k+1}| =|z_1 z_2 z_3...z_k z_{k+1}| $$

q.e.d

Comment: +1 nice use of MSE. If you had this answer on your mind from the beginning, there is an option of "answer your own question" when you ask a question. You could have used it. If you hadn't, well, this is nearly the same answer as Saketh Malyala.

Answer (score 0):

A gory proof(as I'm unable to provide intuition):
It is enough to prove it for two: $z=x\cdot y$. This can be inductively extended for $n$.

Let $x=a+ib, y=c+id\Rightarrow z=(ac-bd)+i(ad+bc)$. We now have
$$|z|=\sqrt{(ac-bd)^2+(ad+bc)^2}$$
And
$$|x|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2},|y|=\sqrt{c^2+d^2}$$
This implies
$$|x\cdot y|=\sqrt{(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)}$$
Now of you compare, you shall find that the statement is indeed true.